# Java concurrent queries

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, benchmarking

I´m building a benchmarkapplication in Java as experiment. The purpose of the tool is to find out how fast a specific database (like Derby, MySQL for example) is in different settings.

At the moment I'm trying to find out how fast a database is when executing multiple queries at the same time.

I thought of creating multiple threads where each thread executes multiple queries. But at the moment the queries seems to be executed after the other query is finished instead of concurrently.

I've got the following (simplified) code:

```
Runner testCase = new Runner();

for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++) {
    Thread testThread = new Thread(testCase);
    testThread.start();
}

public class Runner implements Runnable {

    public void run() {

      for (int i = 0; i < Benchmarker.QUERY_COUNT; i++) {

        stopwatch2.start();
        List<Person> selectData = dataHandler.selectData();
        stopwatch2.stop();
        counter += stopwatch2.getStopwatchValue();

       }
    }
}
```

The cpu of mine testsystem has two cores so it should be possible to run two multiple threads at a time, right?

Somebody an idea how to implement this option?

Thank you for your time and help!

**UPDATE - added selectData method code**:

```
public List<Person> selectData() {

List<Person> data = new ArrayList<Person>();

try {
    // Select all persons from the database
    ResultSet resultSet = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM PERSON ORDER BY name").executeQuery();

    // Add all the persons to a arraylist
    while (resultSet.next()) {
    data.add(new Person(resultSet.getString("name")));
    }

    // Close the resultset
    resultSet.close();

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Derby.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

return data;
}
```

Comment: if you put `System.out.println` right after the `for`, did it prints before you get the query results?

Comment: Yes it does but after the for loop I print the total executed time of the threads. And because the threads aren't finished yet the time is incorrect. 
When I add testThread.join() in the for-loop the time is printed after all executed threads are ready but the threads wait for each other completion. So thread 1 starts and finishes before thread 2 starts etc.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your benchmark application using eclipse for example and find out in which method are the other threads blocked while waiting for the first one to finish?

Comment: If the for loop in Runner only does the code you added, I would move the stopwatch calls and the counter updating to before and after the for loop, respectively, so you have less overhead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. You have to wait until all Threads have finished. This can be done manually, but it is much easier to not use Threads, but an [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) which offers you methods like `invokeAll()` or `awaitTermination()` that do this for you. To get an `ExecutorService`, use the methods from the `Executors` class. This class also offers methods to wrap `Runnable` into `Callable`. So in the main method you would create an `ExecutorService`, submit all the runnables in the for loop, call `shutdown()` and `awaitTermination()`. Then, print the value of the counter.
2. You have to take care of adding the times correctly. For this it is important that each `Runnable` instance uses its own stopwatch, so the `stopwatch2` variable needs to be a local variable of `run()`. Also, the `counter` variable cannot be a normal long, but it needs to be an [AtomicLong](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html). Otherwise the times of some threads could get lost, because normal addition is not an atomic operation (two threads could try to add their times to the counter variable at the same time, which would probably cause a wrong result).

Here's the code:

```
void runTests() {
  Runner testCase = new Runner();
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

  for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++) {
    executor.execute(testCase);
  }
  executor.shutdown();
  executor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  System.out.println(counter.toString());
}

private AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

public class Runner implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
      StopWatch stopwatch2 = ... // get a stopwatch instance here

      for (int i = 0; i < Benchmarker.QUERY_COUNT; i++) {

        stopwatch2.start(); // this needs to reset the stopwatch to 0
        List<Person> selectData = dataHandler.selectData();
        stopwatch2.stop();
        counter.addAndGet(stopwatch2.getStopwatchValue());

       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and set your reaction as accepted answer when it works:)! One more question: how can I stop the stopwatch of a thread when the thread goes to a waiting state and at a later time resumes for I don't want to add the time the thread is not actually running.

Comment: @NickGreen This depends on the implementation of your stopwatch. Where did you get it from? Perhaps it has a pause() method or something similar?

Comment: It's mine own class.. But the problem is: I want to get only the execution time of 'dataHandler.selectData();' for each Runner. And because the threads can be pushed to a waiting state and later be resumed the measured time in stopwatch is higher than it should be because it adds the inactive time of the Runner.

Comment: @NickGreen How to you push the threads to a waiting state? You would probably have to signal this to the thread and let it pause its stopwatch.

Comment: @Philipp Wendler: I don't push the threads to a waiting state but the os scheduler can give the cpu time at a random time to random a thread.

Comment: Its not possible for the thread to get notified on such an action. You might check the Java Management API if you can get such data from there (but it's probably quite difficult and not very precise, I'd guess).

Comment: Yes, it's probably not possible in a exact way (what it should be in this case) so I'll try something else. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3):

If you share the same SQL Connection between the threads then that might be your problem. In general you should avoid sharing the same connection between different threads and use connection pools instead.

Comment: Also, be careful in that situation about maxing out the connection pool and limiting throughput that way.

Comment: I open the connection before the Runner for-loop and close the connection after the for-loop. The connection is opened with the following code: DriverManager.getConnection(this.getServerUrl()); Where the getServerUrl() returns a JDBC connection url.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of the behaviour you describe is that `dataHandler.selectData()` either is `synchronized` or relies on a `synchronized` method do the work.

To solve this, you either need to remove the synchronization (obviously without breaking things), or have a separate `dataHandler` per thread (provided the class in question supports that.)

Comment: I added the selectData code. Also, each thread already has it's own dataHandler.

Comment: Are those data handlers sharing the same SQL connection?

Comment: No, each has it's own connection: connection = DriverManager.getConnection(this.getServerUrl()); Where the serverurl is something like: jdbc:derby://localhost:port/db;create=false